# In cases such as Tinker v. Des Moines, what did the plaintiffs sue the government for?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court

I was reading about the *Tinker v. Des Moines Independent Community School District* case, and noticed that it (as do many cases) began with a lawsuit, with the Tinker family suing the government.  However, I couldn't find anything about what they were suing *for.*  Money? A change of school policy? (what did they receive for winning the case/what were they trying to get from the government?)

More generally, **I'm wondering what people generally sue the government for in cases involving constitutional or law-granted rights** such as freedom of expression, where there ***aren't any significant monetary damages***.  (the plaintiff hasn't lost any money/resources as a result of the government's alleged violation of his rights.)

Comment: You're going to have to pick which of these questions you want answered; there are many kinds of relief that can be requested under different circumstances in these kinds of suits, so you can ask about that. Or you can ask specifically for what relief plaintiffs prayed in Tinker; but right now it's not clear which you'd prefer.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Law.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tinker* was filed under 42 USC 1983, which establishes liability for deprivation of constitutional rights under color of law. Money is not the only thing lawsuits are brought for; *Tinker* was seeking injunctive relief, which means they wanted a court order telling the school not to punish the students for wearing their armbands. Section 1983 explicitly allows injunctive relief.